# Cosa significa "di punto in punto"?

Tags: meaning, idioms

Nel romanzo *Il fu Mattia Pascal*, di Luigi Pirandello, ho letto:

> E seguivo con gli occhi la dolce fanciulla in quella sua cura gentile, aspettando **di punto in punto** che ella levasse lo sguardo verso la mia finestra. Ma invano. Sapeva che stavo lì; ma, quand'era sola, fingeva di non accorgersene. Perché?

Non capisco il significato della locuzione "di punto in punto". L'ho cercata nel Dizionario dei Modi di Dire Hoepli e anche alla voce "punto" in altri vocabolari, ma non ho trovato nulla a riguardo. Sapreste spiegarmi qual è il suo significato?

Comment: Credo in questo caso significhi "di istante in istante" ovvero "lentamente" e questa locuzione serva ad accentuare appunto l'esasperante lentezza dell'attesa che la ragazza alzi lo sguardo.

Comment: Non è che la fanciulla sta ricamando?

Comment: @Gio: No, sta innaffiando i vasi di fiori.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Il significato dell'espressione "di punto in punto" è che il narratore seguiva lo sguardo della dolce fanciulla con continuità, senza distrarsi, evidentemente per non perdere nemmeno un breve guizzo degli occhi che avrebbe rivelato un'attenzione.

Una espressione equivalente, più moderna, potrebbe essere "istante per istante" oppure "attimo per attimo".